# Is "01234|MY_NAME" = "%s|%s"?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm having trouble understanding the result of this:

```
    fscanf(FILE,"%s|%s", str1, str2);
    printf("Number:%s, Name:%s", str1, str2);
```

Content of FILE:

```
 01234|MY_NAME
```

Expected Output:

```
 Number:01234, Name:My_NAME
```

Output:

```
 Number:01234|MY_NAME, Name:╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠01234|MY_NAME
```

Can someone explain why it gives that output?

P/s: I've solved it with this code:

```
    fscanf(FILE,"%[^|]|%[^|]", str1, str2);
    printf("Number:%s, Name:%s", str1, str2);
```

But I still don't understand why "%s|%s" gives the previous output.

Comment: You may find the [documentation for `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and particularly the section of format specifiers and how they work, to be helpful. I suspect you need a `[set]` configuration, but you will ultimately confirm that.

Comment: This kind of parsing job is better done with `fgets` (or `getline`, if available) and `strtok` (or `strsep`, if available).  `scanf` is almost always more trouble than it's worth, even ignoring  how`%s` is every bit as dangerous as `gets` and numeric overflow provokes undefined behavior.

Comment: "I still don't understand why "%s|%s" gives ... Number:01234|MY_NAME, Name:╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠01234|MY_NAME".  Is "Number:01234|MY_NAME" confusing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%s` directive tells `fscanf` to skip over any initial whitespace and read 1 or more non-whitespace characters into the argument `char *`.

`01234|MY_NAME` is all non-spacey, so it ends up being placed in `str1` by the first `%s`.

Then the `|` in the format string tells `fscanf` to read a literal `|` character. This fails because there is no input left. At this point `fscanf` gives up and returns `1` to indicate that it successfully filled one of the variables.

However, your program ignores the return value from `fscanf`, so it doesn't realize what happened. It blindly outputs `str1` (containing `01234|MY_NAME`) and `str2` (which is uninitialized and prints garbage until it happens to find a `'\0'` in memory).